# C# Automatically Detecting the computer name/ file path

Tags: c#

I am making a program to distribute to people. Currently I'm using:

```
bitmap.Save("C:/My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I want to make it to auto detect their computer file path to desktop so it will save to the folder on the desktop.

I'm looking to use This code:

```
string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
filePath =filePath +@"\Error Log\";
string extension = ".log";
if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
{
Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
}
```

How would I implement that?

Comment: Why aren't you using the code, then?

Comment: `I'm looking to use This code` seems like you already know what to do, so what's the answer?

Comment: The Thing is it isnt working..... Idk where to put it anymore.,,

Comment: I'm a noob to this! I just started 2 days ago

Comment: Put that code in a method and then call that method?

Comment: `The Thing is it isnt working` What does it say?  *I'm too lazy to do it*?

Comment: What I'm saying is im looking for help i'm new to C#

Comment: @DevonFelix And What I'm saying is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I did look at some stuff but now its fixed but thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything in place. Just save the bitmap to the filePath that you created instead of 
`"C:/My OVMK Photos//OpenVMK"`

```
bitmap.Save(filePath + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that it's not working for some reason.  You need to:

1. Make sure that you already have an "Error Log" folder on the desktop
2. Use `Path.Combine` to combine filepath with "Error Log", rather than concatenation

Answer (score 0):

Use a function like this

```
void SaveToDesktop(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    filepath = Path.Combine(filePath,"Error Log");
    if (!Directory.Exists(filePath))
    {
      Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
    }
    filepath = Path.Combine(filepath, DateTime.Now.ToString("image_yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".jpg");
    bitmap.Save(filepath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

then instead of using `bitmap.Save`

do `SaveToDesktop(bitmap);`